# Update table with overlap date range and change status

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table with following column and I would like to update it as following.
The Logic is the start date take the date will be updated if overlap with following rules: take the earliest start date and enddate of the latest row with overlapping date based on member id. And the status of the remaining overlap column will be updated to 2. Hope someone could help.

```html
ID MemberID StartDate   EndDate      Status
1  2        2015-01-01  2015-02-28   1
2  2        2015-02-01  2015-02-03   1
3  2        2015-02-01  2015-03-01   1
4  1        2015-02-01  2015-02-28   1   
5  3        2015-02-01  2015-02-28   1
6  2        2015-05-01  2015-05-20   1


I would like to update to
ID MemberID StartDate   EndDate      Status
1  2        2015-01-01  2015-03-01   1
2  2        2015-01-01  2015-03-01   2
3  2        2015-01-01  2015-03-01   2
4  1        2015-02-01  2015-02-28   1   
5  3        2015-02-01  2015-02-28   1
6  2        2015-05-01  2015-05-20   1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it :

```
update a set 
    a.startdate = 
            (select min(startdate) from @table where memberID = a.memberID), 
    a.enddate = 
            (select max(enddate) from @table where memberID = a.memberID),
    a.status = 
            case when a.id = 
                    (select min(id) from @table where memberID = a.memberID) 
                 then status else 2 
            end 
from @table a
```

Comment: hi this does not work if the date is not overlap. i want it to be combine only when date is overlap but do not combine when date range is not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
---- Creating CTE for finding overlapped dates 
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT A.ID,
       B.ID AS MAPPED_ID,
       A.MEMBERID,
       B.STARTDATE,
       B.ENDDATE,
       B.STATUS
FROM   #YOUR_TABLE A
JOIN   #YOUR_TABLE B ON B.STARTDATE <= A.ENDDATE-- Condition for finding the overlapped dates
                    AND B.ENDDATE >= A.STARTDATE
                    AND A.MEMBERID = B.MEMBERID)-- end here
UPDATE T
SET    T.STARTDATE = A.STARTDATE,
       T.ENDDATE = A.ENDDATE,
       T.STATUS = A.STATUS
FROM   #YOUR_TABLE T
       JOIN (SELECT ID,
                    MEMBERID,
                    STARTDATE,
                    ENDDATE,
                    STATUS=CASE
                             WHEN RN > 1 THEN 2
                             ELSE 1
                           END
             FROM   (SELECT      T.ID,
                                 T.MEMBERID,
                                 CS1.STARTDATE,
                                 CS2.ENDDATE,
                                 ROW_NUMBER() -- ROWNUMBER FOR FINDING THE STATUS
                                   OVER(
                                     PARTITION BY T.MEMBERID, CS1.STARTDATE, CS2.ENDDATE
                                     ORDER BY T.ID) AS RN
                     FROM        #YOUR_TABLE T
                     CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(MIN(STARTDATE)AS DATETIME) AS STARTDATE --- FINDING MIN(STARTDATE) FOR THE OVERLAPPED GROUP
                                  FROM   CTE A
                                  WHERE  A.ID = T.ID) CS1
                     CROSS APPLY (SELECT ENDDATE -- FINDING LAST ENDDATE FOR THE OVERLAPPED GROUP (IE RN=1)
                                  FROM   (SELECT ENDDATE,--- ROW_NUMBER FOR THE OVERLAPPED GROUPS
                                                 ROW_NUMBER()
                                                   OVER(
                                                     ORDER BY B.MAPPED_ID DESC) AS RN
                                          FROM   CTE B
                                          WHERE  B.ID = T.ID)A
                                  WHERE  A.RN = 1)CS2)A)A ON A.ID = T.ID

SELECT *
FROM   #YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: The previous statement must be terminated before a WITH/CTE to avoid errors, so that i added a semi-colon before cte.

Comment: Hi Paul thanks for the help. But what i would like to achieve here is not to update the end date with the max end date, rather the end date that was in the last row of same member id if its date overlap. other than that, i would like to have an update statement instead of select. Appreciate i you could help.